# SVG files to render on PDF via CSHTML

Tags: css, asp.net-core, svg, razor, rotativa

How can SVG files loading from Model to be rendered to rotativa pdf.

**.cshtml**:

```
<img src="temp file path goes here(ex:c://user/temp/scgfile.tmp)" alt="" />
```

If we have files with SVG tags , gets displayed in the PDF. But these files comes from the model with its temp path which can be either PNG or SVG. PNG displays but SVG fails to.

Comment: Please recheck the SVG file extension, are you sure the file extension is ".tmp"? As far as I know, it is the temporary file extension. Besides, to display the SVG file in html page, you could use the `<object>` element, like this: `<object type="image/svg+xml" data="~/img/404.svg"> </object>`.

Comment: @ZhiLv: Yes, as the path of the file taken from Path.GetTempFileName() - This comes as .tmp. PNG file works same way, but svg doesnt.

Comment: Try to use F12 developer Console or Network tools to check whether there has any error. Besides, navigate to the related folder and check whether the svg file is in the correct folder or not.